# Show duration (in minutes) to hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, time, helper

I want to display the duration of a movie. Right now the `movie.duration` is shown in `minutes` (integer)

```
%b Duration: #{ @movie.duration } # 134 mins
```

Does rails have a time helper to show this is in a more human-readable way? Something like this:

```
Duration: 2h 23min
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) might help you.

You can use it like this:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(0, 143.minutes)
# => "about 2 hours"
```

To use an integer / float you'd need to convert to seconds manually:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(0, 143 * 60)
```

---

You could also calculate it like this:

```
"#{@movie.duration/60}h #{@movie.duration % 60}min"
```

The division will give you the hours, while the modulo will give you the minutes.

---

Finally, for the format specified in your question, there's a Gist you can use for the code [here](https://gist.github.com/csanz/669588).

Comment: Note that distance_of_time_in_words is i18n-aware and has a double interface : it can be used directly on a duration : distance_of_time_in_words(6270.873) #=> environ 2 heures (in French)

Answer (score 7):

Try Following

```
def formatted_duration(total_minute)
  hours = total_minute / 60
  minutes = (total_minute) % 60
  "#{ hours }h #{ minutes }min"
end
```